# Express redirect sends correct file however the browser does not load this file

Tags: node.js, express, web

I have a post request that essential does the following

```
app.post('/delete_favourite', requireLogin, function(req, res) {
     res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
});
```

This returns the URL of the page that made the request and so essentially should reload it. When I press on the button that causes this post request to happen the new html file is received in the browser (i can see this in the network tab of the chrome inspector) however it does not get rendered and the page just remains on its current page

Comment: How do you send your `POST` request exactly?

Comment: using jquery as such       $.post( '/delete_favourite', {filename: id} ,function(req, res) {});

Comment: using query as follows `$.post( '/delete_favourite', {filename: id} ,function(req, res) {});`